# Jest encountered an unexpected token with React/pnpm

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, vite, pnpm, uppy

`/Users/mac/Desktop/project/node_modules/.pnpm/@uppy+core@3.0.4/node_modules/@uppy/core/lib/index.js:1
({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export { default } from './Uppy.js';
^^^^^^

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

  1 | import { catchError, from, map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
> 2 | import Uppy from '@uppy/core';
    | ^
  3 | import AwsS3 from '@uppy/aws-s3';
  4 | import { handleError, toResponseData } from 'utils/api';
  5 | import { fetcher } from './fetch';`
```

I used `"jest": "29.3.1"` and pnpm for installing node packages and used `vite` for building.

Comment: Shooting into dark here, but I think it has something to do with the ability of the packager to process ES6 modules. The error says "Unexpected token 'export'" which highlights a lack of support for the ES6 syntax. Try checking your bundler settings, maybe there is an easy config fix available.